# ¿Con el bucle "for" puedo realizar un búsqueda en una lista?

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Tengo varias dudas con el bucle `for`:

- Sé que es un iterador, pero, ¿Qué diferencia tiene con el bucle `while`?
- ¿Puedo realizar una búsqueda con el `for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python un bucle `for` es una sintaxis especial para operar con iteradores.

Cuando tú haces:

```
for e in iterable:
   codigo
```

Básicamente ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Python invoca `iter(iterable)` sobre el iterable que hayas especificado tras la palabra `in`. Esto le proporciona lo que se llama un *iterador* que es un tipo de objeto sobre el que se puede hacer `next()` para obtener el siguiente elemento.
2. Hace `next()` sobre el iterador obtenido en 1.
3. Si se produce la excepción `StopIteration`, es que no hay elementos sobre los que iterar, por lo que sale del bucle. El `for` se da por terminado
4. Si no hay excepción, el valor retornado por `next()` se asigna a la variable `e` que hayas puesto antes de la palabra `in`.
5. Se ejecuta el `codigo` que haya en el cuerpo del `for`. Ese código puede usar la variable `e` para acceder al elemento sobre el que se está iterando
6. Terminado el `codigo`, vuelve al paso 2.

Por tanto, en el fondo el bucle `for` es una forma encubierta de bucle `while`, que en concreto sería el siguiente:

```
iterable_tmp = iter(iterador)
while True:
    try:
        e = next(iterable_tmp)
    except StopIteration:
        break               # Salir del bucle
    codigo
```

Por tanto cualquier cosa que puedas hacer en el `codigo` de este `while` puedes hacerlo también en un `for`.

Por ejemplo supongamos que queremos mirar si una lista dada contiene o no un cierto dato:

```
lista = [1, 2, 50, 10, 3]
dato = 10
```

Se haría en la forma siguiente:

```
encontrado = False
for elemento in lista:
    if elemento == dato:
        encontrado = True
        break
```

Al terminar este bucle, la variable `encontrado` será `True` si el dato se encontró, o `False` si no.

Answer (score 1):

**Los ciclos for** son utilizados para ciclos que ya está definido el número de iteraciones, y **los ciclos while** sirven mejor para ciclos donde el número de iteraciones puede variar dependiendo de dos factores:

1. De los valores que se “comparan” de manera inicial, pudiendo ser que, debido a la condición no se lleguen a ejecutar
2. Las operaciones que se realicen dentro del mismo ciclo.

Y sobre tu otra pregunta, según que necesites buscar y en que ambito (archivos, arrays, etc) podrias o no utilizarlo ya que podrian existir mejores alternativas o metodos ya creados para ese tipo de problema.

Espero me deje entender ;) Saludos