# Funcionamiento de yield from

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield

¿Podría alguno de ustedes explicarme qué hace ***yield from*** y para qué sirve, junto a un breve ejemplo de código?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Introducción: `yield`

El `yield` se usa en Python para construir generadores.

Un generador es un tipo de función que puede, por así decir, retornar un valor sin terminar del todo su ejecución, siendo posible reanudarla después. `yield` es la forma de hacer uno de estos "retornos especiales". Aparte de eso también puede contener `return` en cuyo caso retornaría definitivamente.

Cualquier función python que contenga `yield` se convierte automáticamente en una **función generadora** y cuando la ejecutas no comienza realmente su ejecución, sino que python crea un *objeto generador* y es sobre ese objeto sobre el cual se puede comenzar la ejecución "parcial", que avanzará hasta encontrar un `yield` dentro de la función.

Un ejemplo:

```
def ejemplo_tonto():
    print("Acabo de comenzar")
    yield 1
    print("Continúo")
    yield 2
    return
```

Si intentas ejecutar esta función normalmente, así:

```
>>> r = ejemplo_tonto()
```

verás que no aparece ningún mensaje, lo que indica que la función realmente no comenzó aún a ejecutarse. `r` es un *generador* y para comenzar a ejecutar realmente esa función hay que hacer `next()` sobre `r`:

```
>>> r
<generator object ejemplo_tonto at 0x7f6ec11563b8>
>>> resultado = next(r)
Acabo de comenzar
>>> resultado
1
```

Como ves, al hacer `next(r)` comienza realmente la ejecución del generador, y ésta se detiene cuando llega al `yield 1`. El `1` es el valor retornado por ese `yield` y será el resultado que nos devuelve el `next()`, el cual en este ejemplo lo guardé en la variable `resultado`. Pero el generador "recuerda" por dónde iba. Si hacemos de nuevo `next()` sobre él, continuará en la línea siguiente al `yield` que lo había dejado pausado:

```
>>> resultado = next(r)
Continúo
>>> resultado
2
```

y de nuevo se ha quedado pausado en el segundo `yield`. Si intentamos otro `next()` más, reanudará su ejecución y alcanzará el `return`, y en este momento termina definitivamente. Este `return` por cierto podría haberlo omitido pues de todas formas hay un `return` implícito al final de toda función.

Cuando el generador se agota (llega a su `return`), Python genera la excepción `StopIteration`:

```
>>> next(r)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

En realidad, un generador proporciona la interfaz de un *iterable*, al permitir ir haciendo `next()` varias veces y generar un `StopIteration` cuando ya no hay más elementos para retornar. Eso me permite usarlo en un bucle `for`, por ejemplo así:

```
>>> for dato in ejemplo_tonto():
...    print(dato)
...
Acabo de comenzar
1
Continúo
2
>>>
```

[Más detalles sobre cómo funciona `for` [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/312508/7123)]

## `yield from`

La sintaxis `yield from` permite *encadenar* generadores. Imagina que tengo ahora este otro generador:

```
def ejemplo_tonto2():
   yield 0
   for dato in ejemplo_tonto():
       yield dato
   yield -1
```

¿Qué ocurre si lo llamas con `ejemplo_tonto2()`?

De momento no ocurre nada, sino que se crea un *generador*. ¿Y si seguidamente haces `next()` sobre el generador creado? Comenzará la ejecución del generador que se ejecutará hasta el primer `yield`, y obtendremos 0. Pero el siguiente `next()` hará que se ejecute el generador interno, para obtener un primer `dato` que valdría 1, y se retornaría ese valor. Así seguiría retornando los datos que le vaya dando el generador interno, hasta salir del bucle `for`. Haciendo `next()` una vez más retornará el -1 del último `yield`. Y otro `next()` causará el `return` (implícito esta vez) y se terminará el generador.

Comprobémoslo:

```
>>> for ej in ejemplo_tonto2():
...    print(ej)
...
0
Acabo de comenzar
1
Continúo
2
-1
```

Pues bien, para este tipo de cosas existe `yield from`. El ejemplo anterior podría haberlo escrito así:

```
def ejemplo_tonto2():
    yield 0
    yield from ejemplo_tonto()
    yield -1
```

Cuando dentro de un generador se usa `yield from`, el generador en cuestión se "pausa" a la vez que conecta su "salida" por así decir, con la del generador que pongas tras `yield from`. A partir de ese momento, todos los `next()` se hagan sobre el generador "externo" llegan directamente al interno, el cual irá retornando sus valores. Cuando el generador interno se agote y cause `StopIteration`, se reanudará la ejeución del generador externo que estaba pausado.

> **Nota**: Antes de que Python 3.5 añadiera la sintaxis `async`/`await`, los `yield` y `yield from` se usaban a modo de "truco" para implementar programación asíncrona y corutinas. No quiero extenderme en esto porque sería muy largo y complejo, pero lo menciono porque tal vez el contexto en que tú has encontrado esta sintaxis sea precisamente ese. Desde Python 3.5 se prefiere la sintaxis `async`/`await`.

Comment: Yield from basicamente es para ahorrarme ese generador anidado, osea sigue estando ahi, pero de una forma mas pythonica.

Comment: Gracias por la "nota" no sabia que de > 3.5 manejaban esos otros mejor.

Comment: @retr0 En realidad, como intenté explicar, no es un mero "azúcar sintáctico" para ocultar un loop que en realidad esté ahí.Sustituye el loop porque "conecta" a quien hace next() sobre el generador externo, directamente con el generador interno. Esa conexión directa dura hasta que el generador interno se agote. Mientras tanto, el generador externo no se ejecuta.

Comment: @retr0  En cuanto lo de python 3.5 cuidado. No he querido decir que async/await sea la "nueva forma" de hacer yield from. No tienen nada que ver. Lo que ocurre es que antes de que se inventara async/await, el yield y yield from se "abusaban" y aparte de usarse para generadores, se usaban para crear corutinas y asincronicidad, siendo todo un poco más farragoso. En Python 3.5+ está mejor separado y ya sólo se debería usar yield/yield from para generadores.